# UWP ListView with responsive columns

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have researched Google, checked out UWP samples but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Basically, I want a listview with auto-resizing grid columns. For example, you have Groove Music Songs View. I want to implement a behavior like that.

Whenever you resize Groove, the listview adjusts itself to the size by expanding, contracting or hiding the columns. I can handle the hiding part using VisualStates and AdaptiveTrigger but can't figure out how to handle the expansion/contraction of the grid.

One other thing to note is that the items are all uniform with same width for each TextBox. They don't appear fuzzy and without a pattern if, by chance, a song's name is longer then usual.

I have this DataTemplate:

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="MediafileUnselectedTemplate">            
            <Grid Height="50">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="titleTxt" Grid.Column="0" Width="400"       TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="Clip" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="artistTxt" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding LeadArtist}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="albumTxt" Grid.Column="2" Width="200" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Album}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="yearTxt" Grid.Column="3" Width="100" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Year}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="genreTxt" Grid.Column="4" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Genre}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="durationTxt" Grid.Column="5" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Length}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

What I can manage:
I can set `MinWidths` or just `Widths` to set them all uniform but then they lose their adaptability and just do not resize according to the page.

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
        <Grid Height="50">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock x:Name="titleTxt" Grid.Column="0"        TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="artistTxt" Grid.Column="1"   Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding LeadArtist}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="albumTxt" Grid.Column="2"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Album}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="yearTxt" Grid.Column="3"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Year}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="genreTxt" Grid.Column="4" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Genre}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="durationTxt" Grid.Column="5" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Length}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: This is quite better but it doesn't work without setting the width on each element. Also, after setting the width the columns become responsive but they stop expanding after a fixed value.

Answer (score 1):

I see in your DataTemplate you set explicit Width for your TextBlocks. Since there, WPF will always keep this width, even if you resize your container control.

1. In place of setting Width of ColumnDefinitions to Auto, set it to "*".
2. Remove the Width attribute of TextBlock.
3. Remove any triggers that set Width on these controls.

This will set all your columns to have the same size and to resize accordingly to your container size.

Comment: Settinng the ColumnWidth to "*" makes all the columns the same size when I want the Title column to be bigger.

Comment: This does not work at all. On the contrary, it breaks the pattern and each textbox has its own width and position.

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Either have all columns the same  width, whatever the content. In that case use "* ". Or you want to always try to display the entire content, in that case, use "Auto". If you set mannualy your width on the TextBlock, it will always keep that width and resizing won't have effect on it. However if you want your title column to take more space, but still resize, use "4*" for example. It will just take 4 times the width of columns you defined with "*"

Comment: When I set the width on each element, it follows the ColumnDefinition pattern. Otherwise, the textblocks just collapse on each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could Use `VisualStateManager` to change the text width individually based on a `VisualState`, for example I change `titleTxt`'s and `artistTxt`'s width based on the `MinWindowWidth`:

```
<UserControl>
       <Grid Height="50" x:Name="myGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <x:Double x:Key="NarrowMinWidth">0</x:Double>
                        <x:Double x:Key="NormalMinWidth">521</x:Double>
                        <x:Double x:Key="WideMinWidth">1200</x:Double>
                    </Grid.Resources>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNarrow">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="titleTxt.Width" Value="100"/>
                                    <Setter Target="artistTxt.Width" Value="100"/>

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateNormal">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="titleTxt.Width" Value="200"/>
                                    <Setter Target="artistTxt.Width" Value="100"/>

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="titleTxt.Width" Value="400"/>
                                    <Setter Target="artistTxt.Width" Value="200"/>

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="titleTxt" Grid.Column="0"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="Clip" Text="{Binding Title}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="artistTxt" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Artist}"  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="albumTxt" Grid.Column="2"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Album}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="yearTxt" Grid.Column="3"  Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Year}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="genreTxt" Grid.Column="4" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Genre}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="durationTxt" Grid.Column="5" Visibility="Visible" Margin="15,0,0,0" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Duration}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  />
            <Border Background="CornflowerBlue" Grid.Column="1" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.